# Android Asynchronous Http Client BinaryHttpResponseHandler Not Firing

Tags: android, android-asynctask

EDIT: I've traced the problem down to the actual image URL. I've found that if I use URLs that I get from my server (e.g.  http://d2pylg92tvoklp.cloudfront.net/users/28970/images_185898_85nte6f1_thumb.jpg) it doesn't work. If I pass ti a static image, like http://forums.terrybrooks.net/Avatars/7691/Dystopia.jpg it works without any problems.

I am using the Asynchonous Http Client (http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) to fetch images from my server, like so:

```
httpclient.get(mThumbs.get(position), new BinaryHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Log.d("Album Adapter", "Getting the image data...");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(byte[] fileData) {
                Log.d("Album Adapter", "Got the image data...");
                Bitmap imageThumb = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(fileData, 0, fileData.length);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(imageThumb);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable e, String response) {
                Log.e("Album Adapter","Can't fetch the image");
            }
        });
```

This is located inside my gridview adapter. When the request is fired, I always see the onStart() log, but I never see any other log - no onSuccess nor onFailure. This happened earlier with my other request trying to use the JSON response handler. When I switched that to the normal AsyncHttpResponseHandler it worked fine, but I can't do that for this unfortunately. Any ideas?

Best regards,
Damir H.